# Compiling GCC from source down to .s assembly file

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, configure, autoconf

I am doing binary code rewriting. The reason I do so is to robust the binary code without having access to its source code. So what I intend to do is to rewrite at the assembly level because it is much much more difficult to rewrite on the disassembly.

What I want is the `.s` assembly file of the programs I want to robust. GCC is one of them. I tried to hack the GCC `Makefile` and add `-save-temps` to every `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` in it. I did the same thing on compiling coreutils and I was successful to get the `.s` file for any program in coreutils like `ls`, `cat`, and etc. However, doing the same thing in GCC `Makefile` I got error. Here is the configure command I used:

```
../gcc-svn/configure --prefix=/opt/mygcc
```

And here is part of the errors I get (Most of which are redefinition errors which makes sense):

```
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:73:10: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__true_type’
   struct __true_type { };
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:73:10: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__true_type’
   struct __true_type { };
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:74:10: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__false_type’
   struct __false_type { };
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:74:10: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__false_type’
   struct __false_type { };
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:77:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__truth_type<<anonymous> >’
     struct __truth_type
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:77:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__truth_type<<anonymous> >’
     struct __truth_type
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:81:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__truth_type<true>’
     struct __truth_type<true>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:81:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__truth_type<true>’
     struct __truth_type<true>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:87:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__traitor<_Sp, _Tp>’
     struct __traitor
            ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:87:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__traitor<_Sp, _Tp>’
     struct __traitor
            ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:95:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__are_same< <template-parameter-1-1>, <template-parameter-1-2> >’
     struct __are_same
            ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:95:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__are_same< <template-parameter-1-1>, <template-parameter-1-2> >’
     struct __are_same
            ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:102:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__are_same<_Tp, _Tp>’
     struct __are_same<_Tp, _Tp>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:102:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__are_same<_Tp, _Tp>’
     struct __are_same<_Tp, _Tp>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:110:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_void<_Tp>’
     struct __is_void
            ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:110:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_void<_Tp>’
     struct __is_void
            ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:117:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_void<void>’
     struct __is_void<void>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:117:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_void<void>’
     struct __is_void<void>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:127:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<_Tp>’
     struct __is_integer
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:127:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<_Tp>’
     struct __is_integer
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:138:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<bool>’
     struct __is_integer<bool>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:138:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<bool>’
     struct __is_integer<bool>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:145:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<char>’
     struct __is_integer<char>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:145:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<char>’
     struct __is_integer<char>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:152:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<signed char>’
     struct __is_integer<signed char>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:152:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<signed char>’
     struct __is_integer<signed char>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:159:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<unsigned char>’
     struct __is_integer<unsigned char>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:159:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<unsigned char>’
     struct __is_integer<unsigned char>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:167:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<wchar_t>’
     struct __is_integer<wchar_t>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:167:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<wchar_t>’
     struct __is_integer<wchar_t>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:176:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<char16_t>’
     struct __is_integer<char16_t>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:176:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<char16_t>’
     struct __is_integer<char16_t>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:183:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<char32_t>’
     struct __is_integer<char32_t>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:183:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<char32_t>’
     struct __is_integer<char32_t>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:191:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<short int>’
     struct __is_integer<short>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:191:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<short int>’
     struct __is_integer<short>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:198:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<short unsigned int>’
     struct __is_integer<unsigned short>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:198:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<short unsigned int>’
     struct __is_integer<unsigned short>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:205:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<int>’
     struct __is_integer<int>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:205:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<int>’
     struct __is_integer<int>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:212:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<unsigned int>’
     struct __is_integer<unsigned int>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:212:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<unsigned int>’
     struct __is_integer<unsigned int>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:219:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<long int>’
     struct __is_integer<long>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:219:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<long int>’
     struct __is_integer<long>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:226:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<long unsigned int>’
     struct __is_integer<unsigned long>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:226:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<long unsigned int>’
     struct __is_integer<unsigned long>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:233:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<long long int>’
     struct __is_integer<long long>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:233:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<long long int>’
     struct __is_integer<long long>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:240:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<long long unsigned int>’
     struct __is_integer<unsigned long long>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:240:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<long long unsigned int>’
     struct __is_integer<unsigned long long>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:261:19: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<__int128>’
 __INT_N(__GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0)
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:261:19: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<__int128>’
 __INT_N(__GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0)
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~         
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:261:76: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<__int128 unsigned>’
 __INT_N(__GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0)
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:261:115: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_integer<__int128 unsigned>’
 __INT_N(__GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0)
                                                                                                                   ^                              
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/array:34,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdtr1c++.h:31:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:279:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct std::__is_floating<_Tp>’
     struct __is_floating
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:42,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:41:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:279:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::__is_floating<_Tp>’
     struct __is_floating
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

<AND THERE ARE MORE ERRORS IN BETWEEN BUT IT TAKES LOTS OF SPACE.>

In file included from ~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/algorithm:60,
                 from ~/gcc/gcc-svn/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:65:
~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/utility:321:12: note: previous definition of ‘struct std::integer_sequence<_Tp, _Idx>’
     struct integer_sequence
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Makefile:1752: recipe for target 'x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/stdtr1c++.h.gch/O2g.gch' failed
make[5]: *** [x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/stdtr1c++.h.gch/O2g.gch] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include'
Makefile:511: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3'
Makefile:418: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '~/gcc/objdir-makehack/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3'
Makefile:15895: recipe for target 'all-stage1-target-libstdc++-v3' failed
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '~/gcc/objdir-makehack'
Makefile:24352: recipe for target 'stage1-bubble' failed
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '~/gcc/objdir-makehack'
Makefile:944: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea how I can get the GCC `.s` file or what is the systematic way to get rid of these errors?

Comment: *Why do you want the assembler files* ? Please **edit your question** to motivate it. It smells *strongly* like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You won't get a *single* assembler file, but thousands of them.

Comment: You should mention your research project in your question. There could be some other ways (I'm thinking of writing your own GCC plugin). And I might be interested by your research project itself....

Comment: If you find a big-endian x86-{32,64} CPU, call the police.

Comment: The switches were not my issue and it was not a big deal to me right now. So I removed them from my question.

Comment: I added more motivation to my question. May I ask why I got -1? I am new to the community and I would appreciate if you let me know my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: I did downvote, but now I just upvoted, because you motivated your question

Answer (score 0):

> For some reasons I want the .S assembly file for gcc

You can't get a single `.S` file (capital `S`). BTW, `.S` files are conventionally hand-written preprocessable assembler code (that is intended to be first handled by the preprocessor). They are converted in some plain `.s` assembler file by the `cpp` preprocessor, and the result is processed by `as`

You could get a `.s` file (lower case `.s`  is assembler code output of `cc1` or `cc1plus`, and input to [`as`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.29/as/index.html)) for every translation unit of the GCC compiler (so **many thousands of such files**, as much as you get `.o` files). And you'll need a *lot* of disk space.

My recommendation is:

First, configure your GCC to just be able to compile it correctly. Perhaps

```
 ../gcc-svn/configure --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 \
    --with-endian=big,little --prefix=/opt/mygcc  --program-suffix=-my
```

might work on your system (I'm surprised: why do you want `--with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --with-endian=big,little` ? I won't use that). You should try. then run `make -j`.

When (several hours later) that did work completely, remove all the files in your build tree, and try again, by appending `CFLAGS=-save-temps` (see [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html))  to your previous (and successful) `configure`  command. See also [this](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Compilers-and-Options.html#Compilers-and-Options) about [defining variables](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Defining-Variables.html#Defining-Variables) for `configure`.

However, if you really want to change a binary compiled from GCC, it may be simpler to change the compiler itself, perhaps by writing your [GCC compiler plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html). Of course, that still takes months of work (the hard part being to understand GCC and its internal representations).

Comment: May I ask what is `--program-suffix=-my`?

Comment: Are you sure about the `CFLAGS+=-save-temps`? It gives me an error: `configure: error: invalid variable name: CFLAGS+`

Comment: Sorry, should try with `CFLAGS=-save-temps`

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was `.s` not `.S`. You are right.

Comment: But you won't get a *single* one. But thousands of them. I don't know what kind of static analysis you are doing, but you'll need to make some kind of "symbolic linking", and that could be difficult. That is why I recommend to *motivate* your question and give more context. BTW, I am very curious and interested about your research project. If you can explain more about it, send me an email!

Answer (score 0):

The "-save-temps" switch only needs to be added to one `CFLAGS` in the Makefile. The flag's name is `BOOT_CFLAGS` for which there is a comment saying "Flags to pass to stage2 and later makes". In my case I used gcc 7.3 and a simple configure command with `--prefix` and that flag resides in line 351 of the Makefile. With that change I was able to get ".s" file for gcc in "./gcc" sub-directory of my build directory.

Thanks for the helpful comments by the way.